# Type Error, cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm reading data in from an API and I'm trying to have the elements in the data array show up in a select tag in HTML using React, but it keeps telling me that the data is not an array even though it seems like it is when I do console.log.

```
render(){
        console.log(this.state.countries.Countries)
        return(
            <div className = "tables-container">
                <h1>Tables</h1>
                <label>Please Select a Country to view data for:  </label>
                <select name = "countries" id = "countries">
                    <option selected = "selected">Select a Country</option>
                    {
                        this.state.countries.Countries.map((data)=>(
                             <option>{data.Country}</option>
                        ))
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

When I run this, it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined." The console.log result reads

```
(188) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

so I'm pretty sure `this.state.countries.Countries` should be an Array, so the map function should work, but it doesn't.
In my constructor I have

```
this.state = {
    countries: [],
}
```

and I have the API fetch in

```
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
            .then((data) => data.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({
                    countries: data
                })
            })
    }
```

I've been stuck on this for an hour now I really need help figuring it out. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us where you create the state, and any places where you update it?

Comment: @NicholasTower Yup, I've just updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.state = {
    countries: [],
}
```

`this.state.countries` starts off as an empty array. It has no `.Countries` property on it, so for your first render, `this.state.countries.Countries` is `undefined`, and you can't map `undefined`.

You need your state to have the same shape before and after you load data. So if you want the `.countries.Countries` nesting, change your initial state to this:

```
this.state = {
  countries: {
    Countries: []
  }
}
```

If you just want one level of nesting, keep your initial values and change the following:

```
// In componentDidMount
this.setState({
  countries: data.Countries
})

// In render
this.state.countries.map(
```